# How can I execute a method when I force close an application

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, nsurlconnection

I want to send logoff details to the server when a user force quits the application. i write code in "applicationWillTerminate".method is executing but the delegates are not getting called and i was unable to logoff. can any one please explain me how can i resolve this problem?

CODE:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {

    [self sendingLogoffDatatoServer];
}

- (void)sendingLogoffDatatoServer
{
    [self.connection cancel];

 //intialize new mutable Data
 NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
 self.receiveData = data;

 //initialize URL that is Going to be Fetched
 NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://service/logout"];

 //initialize a request from URL
 NSMutableURLRequest * request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[url standardizedURL]];

//set HTTP Method
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

//initalize a post data


NSString *postData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"email=%@",emailString];
NSLog(@"%@",postData);
//set Request Content Type
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

//set POST Data of Request
[request setHTTPBody:[postData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

//initialize a Connection from Request
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
self.connection = conn;

//strat the Connection
[conn start];
NSLog(@"Connection Started");
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
  [self.receiveData appendData:data];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
 if(error)
{
    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"TITLE" message:@"Couldn't Connect to the Server. Please Try Again."  delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [errorAlert show];
 }
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
  NSLog(@"Posted");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, after this line

```
//initialize a Connection from Request
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
self.connection = conn;

//strat the Connection
[conn start];
NSLog(@"Connection Started");

[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.0];  // call the sleeper time interval


-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
 NSLog(@"Posted");
 [[NSThread mainThread] exit];   // call the thread break or use exit (0)
}
```

Comment: For now it is working fine.i want to know is there any problem in future if we do like this.

Comment: no it does not affect anything, this is one type of usage, k any way my brother if my answer is useful give the up vote for the answer

Comment: Thanks.Ya sure.But i don't have reputation.any way i am accepting u r answer.

Comment: ha hah aha hah a, I think u used my code for request the webservice

Comment: Best to use is NSURLSession try using that